# Android SparseArray is null when running a Unit Test

Tags: android, unit-testing, null

I have a unit test for a kotlin object which uses a SparseArray.
The test always failed because the SparseArray is always null despite it's initialization.

```
object Exam : KoinComponent {
var map = SparseArray<Char?>()
        init {
            map.put(0, 'a')
            map.put(1, 'b')
            map.put(2, 'c')
            map.put(3, 'd')
        }

fun getChar(key: Int): Char? {
    Log.d(KOIN_TAG, "" + map.get(key))
    return map.get(key)
}


class ExamTest : KoinTest {
    @Test
    fun getCharTest(){
        assertEquals(Exam.getChar(0), 'a')
    }
}
```

I debugged this test and it ran through the init of the Array, but the value is always null.
Please help me to solve this case. Thank you

Comment: (The braces are not balanced in the first code block, and indentation is questionable. Consider using *code fences* (e.g.`~~~`, see post edit cheat panel).)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that SparseArray is part of Android and not of Java. In an unit test you are only able to use Plain old Java Objects and no android classes or dependencies (for example from package android.util).

Therefore you have to mock the SparseArray in your test.

For example you can use Mockito:

```
private var map: SparseArray<Char> = SparseArray()
map = mock()
```

Unfortunately you are not able to pass the mocked sparse array to your object.
So you cannot test your specific example like this.

Another solution would be to use the **Robolectric framework** if you want to test a class with platform dependencies. http://robolectric.org/